# Python not importing dotenv module

Tags: python, django, module

I am setting up an `imageboard` that uses `Django` and when i try to load `manage.py` for the first time i am greeted with this error message

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

```
File "./manage.py", line 3, in <module>
    import dotenv
```

**ImportError:** `No module named 'dotenv'`

I have tried using python-dotenv rather than dotenv and it still doesn't work. Any solution for this?

Comment: are you using virtual environment?

Comment: what is a virtual environment?

Comment: @AvijitDasgupta I'm not sure, could you tell me what it is and how to use it?

Answer (score 24):

Do you have `dotenv` installed (and not `Python-dotenv`)?

`Python-dotenv` and `dotenv` seem to cause conflicts when you have those both installed. Make sure you uninstall dotenv first, and uninstall python-dotenv too for good measure:

```
pip uninstall dotenv
pip uninstall python-dotenv
pip install python-dotenv
```

Comment: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/typing.pyc'
Consider using the `--user` option or check the permissions.

Comment: Also make sure that you installed `python-dotenv` rather than `dotenv-python`